# Uncaught ReferenceError when deploying to Netlify

Tags: javascript

I have published a git repo (https://github.com/GeorgeFlorian/Forkify-App) to Netlify (https://forkify-jorje.netlify.app/) after following an Udemy tutorial:

Everything works locally, but when I deploy it I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Fraction is not defined
    at View.js:96
```

`Fraction` is not even inside `View.js` module: https://github.com/GeorgeFlorian/Forkify-App/blob/main/src/js/views/View.js

It is inside another one: https://github.com/GeorgeFlorian/Forkify-App/blob/main/src/js/views/recipeView.js

I don't know how to recreate this bug. All I did was follow the tutorial. The tutor's deployment worked, mine did not.
This is `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "forkify-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "default": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html --open",
    "build": "parcel build index.html --dist-dir ./dist"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/GeorgeFlorian/Forkify-App.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/GeorgeFlorian/Forkify-App/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/GeorgeFlorian/Forkify-App#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.0.1",
    "parcel": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.19.2",
    "fractional": "^1.0.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9"
  }
}
```

I can't find anything relevant online and that's why I've posted here.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error, did the same JS Udemy course by Jonas lol. I found out the problem has to do something with parcel hoisting. Insert `--no-scope-hoist` in front of the build command like this & try

```
parcel build index.html --no-scope-hoist
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different package Fracty instead of Fractional

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, none of those 2 packages mentioned are working at this time. For those encountering the same issue, uninstall Fractional and deploy again. It will work, but another solution needs to be applied to cover for the uninstalled package

```
npm un Fractional
```

then

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'Removed Fractional'
```

then

```
git push origin master
```

Test and all app functions should be back to normal, as tested on local, but the fractional features that you'll have to replace.